# .NET threading question

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there any essential difference between this code:

```
ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(SomeMethod);
starter.Invoke();
```

and this?

```
ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(SomeMethod);
Thread th = new Thread(starter);
th.Start();
```

Or does the first invoke the method on the current thread while the second invokes it on a new thread?

Comment: You're not actually asking a threading related question. The heart of your question is, "What does the Delegate.Invoke method do?" Answer that and you'll have your answer.

Comment: In any case, if you've got access to it, you should forget the Thread API and go for the Tasks one :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not the same.

Calling `new ThreadStart(SomeMethod).Invoke()` will execute the method on the current thread using late binding.  This is much slower than `new ThreadStart(SomeMethod)()`, which is in turn a little bit slower than `SomeMethod()`.

Calling `new Thread(SomeMethod).Start()` will create a new thread (with its own stack), run the method on the thread, then destroy the thread.

Calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { SomeMethod(); })` (which you didn't mention) will run the method in the background on the thread pool, which is a set of threads automatically managed by .Net which you can run code on.  Using the ThreadPool is much cheaper than creating a new thread.

Calling `BeginInvoke` (which you also didn't mention) will also run the method in the background on the thread pool, and will keep information about the result of the method until you call `EndInvoke`.  (After calling `BeginInvoke`, you **must** call `EndInvoke`)

In general, the best option is `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: It not really valid to say that one of the options is better than the others. They do different things. ThreadPool threads are for high-turnover, finite work items. New threads are when you want a new thread. (however, I was not the down-voter)

Comment: @Kennet: That's why I wrote **In general**.  However, you should only make a new thread if you need the `Thread` object, if you need STA, or if it will run for a very long time.  Also, it was downvoted before I wrote that.

Comment: Thanks, SLaks. ThreadPool is exactly what I want - I was creating new Threads to repeatedly execute a short-lived task, and it sounds like the ThreadPool is a more appropriate choice for this.

Comment: Well, ThreadPool works great, except it exposed a different problem. Basically, I'm using these threads to load up audio buffers and play them with the waveOutWrite API method, because you can't call waveOutWrite directly from a waveOut callback. This works fine, except that I now need to also occasionally call the waveOutGetPosition method. Apparently, if I call this method from one thread while waveOutWrite is called from a different thread (which happens randomly) I get a deadlock and my app hangs.

Comment: I think what I need is a single Thread that I create once and then Invoke repeatedly to execute the waveOutWrite method. I could then safely call waveOutGetPosition from this same Thread, although I'm not sure how to do that. If, say, I want to click a button on my form, get the wave position and display it in a label, how do I do that? If I just call the method, it will execute on the UI thread, which is different from the thread calling waveOutWrite.

Comment: I can ask this as a separate question if you like. :)

Answer (score 3):

In case SLaks' answer is not totally clear:

> does the first invoke the method on the current thread while the second invokes it on a new thread?

Yes.

Comment: Sometimes too much information is overwhelming, so I gave the option of a direct answer to his question.  I upvoted your answer btw.